# How to validate/authenticate URL with Spring-Security based on request parameter?

Tags: spring, url, authentication, spring-security, url-parameters

I have single method for add/edit business profile like given below.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/businessprocess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addOrEditBusiness(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "businessId") Integer businessId,
             @Valid @ModelAttribute("businessForm") BusinessForm businessForm){
             //logic goes here.
        }
```

There must be session live when businessId is not null while accessing `businessprocess` URL. because user cannot edit his business profile without login. But user should do registration without session. Is there any way to do it with spring security ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just protect the url allow only access for authenticated/authorized users. Put a link to a registration form on the login page. That way only registered users are allowed access others first need to register.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, but I didn't get.. :(

Comment: What is it you don't understand? You are using spring security, let that secure the URL with `intercept-url` so that user are required to login. If they don't have an account they cannot login. You aer using Spring Security then utilize it and don't try to work around it.

Comment: but, I need to allow same `url` if businessId is not present in `url` request parameter, otherwise not. I am not sure how to do it with spring security.

Comment: Then don't use an intercept URL use a `@PreAuthorize` annotation with an expression which determines if the parameter is null allow, else user needs to be logged in.

Comment: if possible, can you give any reference link or small example?

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-pre-post-annotations. Something like this `@PreAuthorize("#businessId != null or isAuthenticated())")` should give access if no businessId is present or if the user is authenticated. Make sure you have enabled processing of pre-post annotations.

Comment: I am able to do with this entry in  security.xml `<security:intercept-url pattern="\A/businessprocess\?businessId.*\Z" access="Business" />` and it's working..is it right way to do?

Comment: That will only work if the `businessId` is part of the URL. In general with a POSt it is part of the request body.